# How to get value from key-value pair in Prolog

Tags: prolog, key-value, keyvaluepair

I have difficulty finding the way to access values from prolog key-value pairs.

```
   gas-[2, 3, 1, 1, 3]
```

Above is an example of my pair, gas is a key, and the list is value. The reason I use this A-B format is because **the term -(A, B) denotes the pair of elements A and B. In Prolog, (-)/2 is defined as an infix operator. Therefore, the term can be written equivalently as A-B.** from [this](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/data).

I want to get the list just by 'gas'.

Comment: Could you provide a MWE?

Comment: Perhaps I'm oversimplifying, but you can just pattern match with unification `Pair = gas-[2, 3, 1, 1, 3], Pair = Key-Values` will bind `Key=gas` and `Values=[2, 3, 1, 1, 3]`. You can also write a predicate as a shortcut `pair_key_values(Key-Values, Key, Values)` and call `pair_key_values(Pair, gas, Values)` where Pair is defined as above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done using SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.1.24) on Windows 10

```
?- use_module(library(pairs)).
true.
```

First an example of constructing the pairs from just a key and value.

```
?- pairs_keys_values(Pairs,[gas],[[2,3,1,1,3]]).
Pairs = [gas-[2, 3, 1, 1, 3]].
```

Now that the syntax of what is expected for key-value pairs is known,

extract a value from a pair given a key.

```
?- pairs_keys_values([gas-[2,3,1,1,3]],[gas],Value).
Value = [[2, 3, 1, 1, 3]].
```

**EDIT**

After looking into this more perhaps what you want instead is not **key-value pairs** but **Association lists** 
See: library(assoc): [Association lists](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=assoc)

```
?- list_to_assoc([a-1,b-2,c-3],Assoc),get_assoc(b,Assoc,Value).
Assoc = t(b, 2, -, t(a, 1, -, t, t), t(c, 3, -, t, t)),
Value = 2.
```

Using your example `gas-[2,3,1,1,3]`

```
?- list_to_assoc([a-1,gas-[2,3,1,1,3],c-3],Assoc),get_assoc(gas,Assoc,Value).
Assoc = t(c, 3, -, t(a, 1, -, t, t), t(gas, [2, 3, 1, 1, 3], -, t, t)),
Value = [2, 3, 1, 1, 3].
```